# How cout is for static duration?

Tags: c++, stream, cout, outputstream, ostream

[cout - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)

> The object is declared in header  with external linkage and
>   static duration: it lasts the entire duration of the program.

I am using Visual Studio. If I go to its declaration it is like,

```
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL extern _CRTDATA2 ostream cout, *_Ptr_cout;
```

I understand its external linkage, but how it is static duration?

Comment: How could it be anything else?

Comment: Are you expecting to see the `static` keyword? All objects declared at namespace level have static duration.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes.. I was expecting `static` keyword. I was not knowing about static duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[basic.stc.static]/1`:

> All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are
>   not local have *static storage duration*. The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the program